# Analogy Laravel [@extends @yield] and [export import] of JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My undestanding of layouts in Laravel is:
main.blade.php will **import** a partial code with @yield:

```
<!-- main.blade.php -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

And the partial code will **export** itself to a specific file:

```
<!-- partial.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('content')
    <p>This is the content of the page.</p>
@endsection
```

If I understand correctly, it's the partial itself that decides where to go? 
If so, big is my headache... I don't understand the logic.
What happens if several views want to use the same partial? Why isn't it the other way round ( `@yield('layouts.partial','title')` ), like in JS, where the one importing the partial indicates its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea. Partials or components don't extend a layout. They are included as is via `@component('components.modal')` or `@include('partials.paginate')`.

What you have here:

```php
<!-- partial.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('content')
    <p>This is the content of the page.</p>
@endsection
```

is not a partial.

This is a page you serve via `return view('path.to.view');` The layout is not the page, otherwise you would be serving the layout. This page now can define, but it does not have to, what layout it extends and what parts of that layout it overwrites, `title` and `content`.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. To summarize, @extends will be "import all" / "inherit from", then say place my content in the target and it's '@yield' (import here) that defines that target.